# Cloud Functions vs Client Side (pricing)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am Android developer
assume if user A want to do something
but A has no point for it

here is my question
firstly, A has to check(using read method) if there is enough point for it and if it is then read another data (using read method again)

but where I have to implement all those checking function?
Client Side or Cloud-Functions(script side)

I wonder if Cloud-Functions is cheaper than client side

sorry for bad explanation but I think you might get it

Comment: those checking functions should be implemented on both sides

Comment: @llya Bursov sorry, but why it should be implemented on both sides? if server-side checked it then client checking is unnecessary I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any data validation *must* be implemented server-side, and should be implemented client-side too. The server-side validation is required, since malicious clients can bypass anything you do in client-side code. But you typically should also do the validations client-side, just so you can give the user better/faster feedback.

For server-side validation you can use Cloud Functions, but also consider using Firebase's server-side security rules, which are available for Cloud Firestore, Cloud Storage, and the Realtime Database. These rules run automatically for any data access, so are auto-enforced once you've written them. Unlike with Cloud Functions, there is no CPU cost to these rules, although (in the case of Firestore) accessing additional documents is a paid operation.

Comment: thanks!! but I don`t understand this part only "so you can give the user better/faster feedback" I think then only server-side checking is faster than checking on both-side

Comment: Nope. When you **also** run a check client-side, you don't have to wait for the server-response. For example: say that you have a maximum length for a field that the user enters. If you do that on the server, you have to submit the data, and wait for the response. If you *also* do it on the client, you can determine it before submitting, or even while the user is typing. You can provide feedback faster, and possibly more detailed (as Firebase for example only give an error message of "permission denied" when an operation is illegal according to the security rules).